flutter: Error exporting data: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel flutter_email_sender)
The problem:
I'm trying to export a CSV file via email using the flutter_email_sender package (Using my MacOS simulator in VSC). However, when I select export button, I receive the error in my debugging console
"flutter: Error exporting data: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel flutter_email_sender)"
**Relevant code
**
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';

Future<void> _exportData(List<Team> teams, List<List<Player>> playersLists) async {
  try {
    List<List<dynamic>> rows = _generateCsv(teams, playersLists);
    String csv = const ListToCsvConverter(eol: '\n').convert(rows);

    final directory = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final File file = File('${directory.path}/export.csv');
    await file.writeAsString(csv);

    String subject;
    if (teams.length >= 2) {
      subject = 'Stats from ${teams[0].teamName} vs ${teams[1].teamName}';
    } else if (teams.isNotEmpty) {
      subject = 'Stats from ${teams[0].teamName}';
    } else {
      subject = 'Stats';
    }

    final Email email = Email(
      body: 'Your CSV file',
      subject: subject,
      recipients: [], // add the recipients' email addresses here
      attachmentPaths: [file.path],
      isHTML: false,
    );

    await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error exporting data: $e');
  }
}


**Pubspec.yaml file
**
dependencies:
  csv: ^5.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.15
  share_plus: ^3.0.4
  file_picker: ^8.1.2
  flutter_email_sender: ^6.0.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

I've reviewed other Stack Overflow questions and have done the following (none of which have resolved the issue):

Rebuild it instead of hot restart/hot reload
Execute flutter run since you changed the pubspec.yaml
try flutter clean

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Please let me know if you need any further information.

Maybe try rebuilding your app, not hot restart, delete de build folder or make flutter pub cache clean

Thank you. I've done all three of those and unfortunately I still experience the error.

you run your project in macos desktop?

The error means there's no implementation for targeted device. In this case you use MacOS Desktop.
From what i see in flutter_email_sender pub dev, MacOS Desktop environment not supported yet. This package only supports:

Android
iOS

You can see the platform compability from here:


Recommendation
There's package similar to this that support MacOS Desktop platform, check mailer package. This package support all platform except web.

